# Schema level encryption in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, encryption, multi-tenant

A multi-tenancy approach for many webapps is to use a separate PostgreSQL schema for each tenant.

In addition to permissions and access controls, is it possible to encrypt a tenant's whole schema using something like PGP?

In my scenario, the webapp connects to PostgreSQL using a single `webapp` user account. In other words, tenants won't connect to the database with their own database user credentials.

Comment: I imagine there isn't a practical way to encrypt the [individual table files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/storage-file-layout.html) stored on disk within the `PG_DATA` directory, as I not sure how any key would be passed to the server to perform the decrypted on a connection-by-connection basis.